# Android SipManager getting error code -11

Tags: android, authentication, sip

I keep getting the error code -11, equivalent to: "Cross-domain authentication required." according to: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipErrorCode.html

Testing with a different account on the same sip server everything worked fine. I restarted the phone & also tested on different phones but I still get the same error.

Does anyone have any ideas? Maybe it's a sip server related issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that is was some server side issue and the google native sip manager returns this type of error that is undescriptive..